# if/else statement not working

Tags: php, html

I have an issue where the if statement doesn't want to work, I'm not sure what is wrong. Regardless, it will always display the if condition. Initially, I have used a provisional code for the combo box which I'll edit later from the internet, to check if the if/else statement works, but it doesn't, and I can't see any reason why. Any clues? I'll be also adding a foreach statement into the select box, like this...

```
    <select>
    <?php
    foreach($bids as $bid)
    {
    ?>
        <option value="tbc">Some PHP code here</option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

This is the current full code I have:

```
<div class="frontpage_sidebar_header">Quick Flight Dispatch</div>
<div class="sidebox_content">
    <?php 
    if(!$bids)
    {
    ?>
        <table width="100%" style="padding: 5px; text-align: center;">
            <tr>
                <td>You haven't booked any flights</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
        <select>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
    <?php
    }
    ?>      
</div>
```

Comment: try to check if array is empty:
if(count($bids) != 0) {}

Comment: `if/else` always work as expected. But sometimes your expectations and php authors' expectations don't match

Comment: @zzwyb89 show the result of `var_dump($bids)` so we can actually see what it contains and its type.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(is_array($bids) && count($bids) > 0)
```

Comment: I cannot imagine how this may work, and the code from the answer - may not. Voting that OP has shown not what he actually had.

Comment: @zerkms i'm too, but if you work on arrays you should use somethink like this.

Comment: Based on OP saying this solved it, it looks like `$bids` is not an array.

Comment: No, you're right, sorry, it displays now just the else condition. Confusing :|

Comment: @Dawid Sajdak: nope, "should" is a wrong word here. You "may" use `if (count($bids) > 0)` or just `if ($bids)` and it won't change anything. It's a matter of preference and project/team code conventions, nothing else.

Comment: @zzwyb89: `var_dump($bids);` **PLEASE** stop guessing and start working with **FACTS**

Comment: @zerkms: Jesus, relax, I forgot to say I'm merely a beginner to PHP and I'm experimenting with this code. It returned NULL. The variable works fine on another page, generated by a template, it displays 'bids' with a foreach statement in a table.

Comment: @zzwyb89: so it's `NULL`. Any more questions? PS: if you're experimenting - just strip all the unnecessary code to demonstrate the "problem". All the divs and tables are not necessary here.

Comment: so, if $bids return null this method will be good for this: is_array();

Comment: @Dawid Sajdak: not actually. The good will be to find out **why** it's null. It's always a good idea to fix the roots of the issue, not the consequences.

Comment: Basically, it's a booking system, whenever I 'book a flight' it should add a bid. In fact, it does display the 'bids' in another page generated by a .tpl file with a foreach statement in a table, but not on the homepage. Is there an extra step I have missed that you can maybe identify?

Comment: @zzwyb89: yes you have missed one - you haven't assigned anything to `$bids`

Comment: `if(!SchedulesData::GetBids(Auth::$userinfo->pilotid))` made it work :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Doing random things isn't a programming ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If `$bids` is an array what do you expect `(!$bids)` to resolve to?

You should write it like:

```
if (count($bids) === 0) {
```

because that is what you mean

Comment: Uhm, if it's an array then `!$bids` equals to `count($bids) === 0`. So it's barely an answer http://ideone.com/eEQ31J

Comment: It still returns the if condition.

Comment: "_it works_" is possibly the worst argument. At my company this argument is penalized by pie/cake for the whole department. If it's not clear enough, it's not good enough.

Comment: @Frits van Campen: it's not clear enough for you and your company, not to everyone in the world. It's clearly stated how php should behave in this case. And the question is about behaviour, not about code conventions. Do you agree that your code is identical to what OP has?

Comment: I will agree that it is functionally equivalent, but the _question_ OP asks is _if/else statement not working_. This only happens if your if-else statements are so unclear you don't know what's going on. I don't see why you think this is such a problem. Why would you defend bad coding practices because _it works_?

Comment: @Frits van Campen: "I will agree that it is functionally equivalent" -- so how do you see this as an answer? "Why would defend bad coding practices" --- omg, who said it is bad? Overusing the `===` is a bad practice as well - it creates a noise and requres a programmer to read more characters to get the idea of the condition, `if (count($bids))` is clearer

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I think zerkms is trying to make a point that you haven't answered the question, all you have done is shown a different way of checking for array contents. As far as what OP wants, it is functionally the same as what he already has.

Comment: This is because the original code is probably correct, functional-wise. But not from a readability point of view. Readability errors are bugs too you know. Dawid's answer does the same thing and OP seems to like it.

Comment: @Frits van Campen: OP doesn't like it anymore ))) PS: your code from readability point of view is *terrible* as well. You see, that's what happens when one person thinks his own *preferences* are the only correct.

Comment: My point is, the `if` statement doesn't capture the expected value correctly `!$bids` implies `$bids` is a boolean, not an array. It now seems `$bids` isn't even an array. How would you go about answering a question like this then?

Comment: Well, it's all just silly. Your code doesn't different from what OP has. That's the fact. Thus it doesn't answer anything (even though it fits your company coding standards)

Answer (score 0):

try to check if array is empty: `if(count($bids) != 0) {}`